# Apache guacamole RDP resize with nginx SSL proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, rdp

How can I get Guacamole's RDP '"Display Update" virtual channel' option working through an SSL nginx reverse proxy?

I have Apache Guacamole configured and working in a VM. When I access an RDP desktop through the guac VM directly via http://guac:8080/, the desktop resizes when the browser window is resized.

When I access the *same* desktop through an SSL nginx reverse proxy, RDP desktop resizing doesn't work.

I'm using the recommended nginx `location` block:

```
        location /guac/ {
            proxy_pass http://guac:8080/;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
            client_max_body_size 1g;
            access_log off;
        }
```

Both guac and nginx hosts are FreeBSD 14.0 vms, but I've had the same experience running guac and nginx in docker containers in an aarch64 Linux VM, so I assume the platform has nothing to do with it.

Why doesn't resizing work through the reverse proxy, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to the `location` block above fixed it.

```
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
```

With the addition of this line, RDP desktops now resize on browser resize when going through the SSL nginx proxy.

I tried several of [nginx's many proxy_* options](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html), but ultimately none of them were needed. Just the Cache-Control header.